# How to efficiently search for substrings across all values in a hashmap?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have data specified in the following manner:

```
<type:id> <relevance-score> <data>
```

Ex.:

```
a:1 0.8 "This is a post by PhD"
a:2 0.9 "Current rep of PhD is 3,800+"
b:1 1.0 "Pikl F'Nandez is not an existing user on stackoverflow"
c:2 1.0 "AJAX is a tag on stackoverflow"
...
```

Assuming that these values are put in a hashmap such that:

```
key = (<type:id>) | value = (<relevance-score>,<data>)
```

Now, if one is to search for the keyword `PhD`, it can be found in two entries in the hashmap. I wish to retrieve all the keys, in descending order of relevance scores, that matches the query string:

```
Example output: a:2, a:1
```

Query string could also be `Pikl` or `Pikl F` or `Pikl F'n` implying that a string matching algorithm is the best way to go about the search.

**Current approach**: Use the Boyer-Moore Algorithm for all the values in the hashmap and store the resulting data into a max heap (on relevance score).

**Time complexity**:

- Boyer-Moore: `O(m+n)`
- Total, for each value `O(q(m+n))` where `q: # of keys in hashmap`
- Also need to add popping of values from heap. Let's assume `O(s)` where `s` is the number of matches. Since `s << q` we could say that the above (searching) is the dominant cost.

**Question:** Is this the most efficient it can get? Is there anything that can be more efficient? Other data-structures/algorithm perhaps, that I may not be thinking about?

Comment: Is Boyer-Moore the right tool? It works by preprocessing the pattern one is looking for, not the target strings being searched. What is it buying you here?

Comment: Not sure. I'm only using it for string matching. A naive approach to start with. Wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing things? What do you suggest?

Comment: How many data items are we talking about? Also, is storing this in a dbms that has good text search capability an option?

Comment: Upto 100,000 easy. It all has to be "in memory" for faster access. So think of designing such a capability from scratch and the above approach is "one" such idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach basically boils down to:

1. Iterate through all data and find ones that match the search string
2. Perform heap sort on all matching data based on the relevance-score

The only difference being that you are performing 2 while you are performing 1, but the resulting time complexity is the same.

Even if we assume that the time for each string search is `O(1)`, total time for string search becomes `O(q)`, and the time for sorting is `O(slog(s))`. Since `s << q`, it is reasonable to claim `O(slog(s)) < O(q)`. In other words, the time taken for string search will always dominate.

The only way that I can think of that achieves a meaningful speed up is to pre-process all data so that the time taken for each string search does indeed become closer to `O(1)`. This would be easier if the query strings were guaranteed to be a list of words rather than random sub-strings. However with query strings such as `Pikl F'n` possible, pre-processing of data will be very difficult. In essence, if you had any information on the type of query strings that you may get, you could pre-process the data accordingly for a faster search.